# Diagonalization of a simple matrix. Arriving at a contradiction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Consider the matrix \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 &1\\ 1 & 1 &1\end{pmatrix}.\end{equation}
The rank of this matrix is $1$ which is less than $3$. So all three eigenvectors are not linearly independent. Therefore, it seems that $A$ cannot be diagonalized by a similarity transformation $S^{-1}AS$ since $S$ is not invertible.

However, the minimal polynomial of $A$ has simple roots. They are $0$ and $3$. Hence, according to the condition of diagonalizability, this should diagonalizable.

Why am I arriving at such a contradiction? Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: you wrote $S$ is not invertible; did you mean $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if, for every eigenvalue $\lambda,$ the geometric multiplicity (dimension of the corresponding eigenspace) is equal to the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner In order to perform $S^{-1}AS$, we need an invertible $S$. $S$ is made out of the eigenvectors of $A$. If those are not linearly independent, $\det S=0$ and $S^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: There are many more than three eigenvectors of this matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues are $\{3,0,0\}.$ So $0$ is a degenerate eigenvalue, and *not a simple root of the characteristic polynomial*. What is the dimension of its corresponding eigenspace? According to Mathematica, the eigenvalues corresponding to $\{3,0,0\}$ are:
$$\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}1\\1\\1\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}-1\\0\\1\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}-1\\1\\0\end{matrix}\right]\right\}. $$
As these are clearly linearly independent, the geometric multiplicity of the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=0$ is therefore $2,$ making your matrix diagonalizable.

Comment: I don't understand this. Rank is less than $3$. If rank is less than 3, doesn't that mean number of linearly independent eigenvectors is less than 3? Doesn't it make $S$ singular?

Comment: Not necessarily!

Comment: Doesn't the rank count the number of linearly independent eigenvectors?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: It makes $A$ singular, not $S$.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "So all three eigenvectors are not linearly independent". @AdrianKeister's answer provides you three independent eigenvectors, so this conclusion is evidently incorrect.

What made you think that it was true?

Was it, possibly, knowing that if the $n$ eigenvalues of and $n \times n$ matrix are distinct, then the eigenvectors are independent? That's a statement of the form $p \implies q$, where $p$ is "the $n$ eigenvalues of and $n \times n$ matrix are distinct" and $q$ is "the eigenvectors are independent". It's not logically allowable to conclude from this that $\sim p \implies \sim q$, as you seem to have done. To see this, consider the case where $p$ is "I am John Hughes" and $q$ is "I live in Rhode Island".

The first does indeed imply the second, but is the statement

```
"If I am not John Hughes, then I do not live in Rhode Island"
```

true? If so, our governor Gina Raimondo is in for a big surprise...

====

More seriously, your comments on some of the answers indicate that you have a great many false beliefs about eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I'd suggest a serious re-study of that material.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point a few misconceptions apart from this?

Comment: "Doesn't the rank count the number of linearly independent eigenvectors", "If rank is less than 3, doesn't that mean number of linearly independent eigenvectors is less than 3?", "it seems that  cannot be diagonalized by a similarity transformation −1 since  is not invertible",  That seems like a long enough list.

Comment: all stemmed from the single misconception that "rank counts the number of linearly independent eigenvectors."

Comment: OK. I'm wrong. Don't bother re-studying. Or maybe I'm not wrong, and my decades of teaching linear algebra suggests correctly that a student who doesn't know how "rank" and "independent eigenvectors" are related really doesn't understand at least one of the two concepts well enough. Time will tell. Regardless, it's not really a mathematical question, hence not appropriate for discussion here.

Comment: No offense. I didn't say you're wrong. I thought the problem was that I confused between "rank counts the maximum number of linearly independent column or rows" and "maximum number of linearly independent eigenvectors". Also I am not really a student of mathematics, and my mathematics is sloppy :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The rank of this matrix is 1 which is less than 3. So all three eigenvectors are not linearly independent.

Why not?

Existence of a full set of independent eigenvectors is completely separate from whether or not the matrix is singular (there is nothing special about zero eigenvalues, vs. non-zero eigenvalues). Consider that the zero matrix has an independent set of eigenvectors, and the classic nonsingular defective matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{array}\right]$$
does not.